# Pros and cons of different MVC frameworks for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

With all the hype around MVC (and rightly so) I've decided to give it a go myself and write my first .NET MVC web application. With a few options to choose from I was wondering **which framework MVC do people recommend**.

- [Microsoft ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/)

  - The above with alternative view engine
- Castle Project - [MonoRail](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/)
- [MVC#](http://www.mvcsharp.org/)
- [Maverick.NET](http://mavnet.sourceforge.net/)

It seems like the first two are really the top contenders. Also some DI container is a natural complement to MVC - MonoRail would [come with one](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html) already while ASP.NET MVC could perhaps work with something like [Unity](http://www.codeplex.com/unity).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the best option would be Microsoft ASP.NET MVC for the following reasons:

- It's official.
- It will have integration with visual studio 2010.
- It was developed by people who work for Microsoft.
- It's free.
- It has a large fan base of developers that swear by it.
- It has lots of documentation and information surrounding it.
- The power of .NET at your fingertips.
- Not limited to developing in one language.

Comment: It is not necessarily a positive thing that it has been developed by Microsoft though. The other points I can agree with.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how that could be a negative thing?

Comment: Actually it integrated with VS 2008 too doesn't it?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is an addon for VS 2008 and integrates with it very well. As I understand it, MVC will ship "in the box" with VS 2010.

Comment: Yah, it isn't part of the VS 2010 first beta, I heard it's going to be in the second beta. You have to use a special installer right now for the beta also.

Comment: A lot of these points are transferable between frameworks, and the other points like "its official" or "It was developed by people who work for Microsoft" mean less than nothing to me.

Comment: Maverick.net has all the features of ASP.Net MVC, except that it also includes regex matching and named groups for form binding urls... You know, a superior product ;)

Comment: I think items 1 and 4 are pratically the same thing, since the .NET full framework is closed source, at least while I'm writing. Even though we can see a stripped down version of the code and .NET FX is truly open source we can't submit patches and have them merged to the full framework.

Comment: @JoshJordan most Microsoft frameworks are considered heavyweight and unnecessary-complex-for-most-use-cases by many people, not to call them bloatware. This means they have a somewhat steep learning curve when you go beyond the provided examples and the systems developed using them are slow.

Comment: @ygormutti do you have data to back that up?

Comment: @JoshJordan for some frameworks, yes. ServiceStack project has pretty good benchmarks. Please, check http://mono.servicestack.net/benchmarks/ and https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Real-world-performance

Comment: This does not speak to your your assertions regarding frameworks being considered heavyweight or unnecessarily complex by many people, nor the assertion that the learning curve is steep. There is some data here about performance for a few specific scenarios, but not for the frameworks in question in this thread. Please be careful making broad statements on Stack Overflow. We like to stay rooted in hard data and not get into dogmatic framework or language debates.

Comment: My statements are broad because your question is broad. There's plenty of reasons why one would choose a software over another because of the company that made it. I focused on technical reasons, the ones that matter here. The benchmarks illustrate why some folks believe MS frameworks are heavyweight. ServiceStack also is a MVC framework, Web API is based on ASP.NET MVC, and ORM, serialization, etc, are common tools in web apps, so I think those scenarios are relevant. Learning curve is a highly subjective matter, so I'm expressing an opinion, just like most contributors to this question.

Comment: You missed one point I think- it has built-in NuGet package collection integration

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft ASP.NET MVC

pro : you can take advantage of .net and your experience with asp.net

Comment: Your con isn't really true, since ASP.NET MVC can run on Mono.

Comment: As of Mono 2.4.2.1, Mono comes prepackaged with ASP.Net MVC, Microsoft's ASP.Net MVC. As stated before, your con is false.

Answer (score 4):

ASP.NET MVC comes with all the common DI frameworks available on code-project, and it is pretty easy to do it yourself, too - I rewrote the StructureMap one to support some specific scenarios (picking the SM configuration out of the route data).

So that deals with the main differentiator you mentioned in the question ;-p

I'd use ASP.NET MVC, personally... but it could come close either way. I simply expect ASP.NET MVC to be more mainstream, what with the "official" card leading to more books/community/etc.

Just look at the tags count here on SO; asp.net-mvc (and similar) 4k+; monorail... hard to find...

Answer (score 0):

It essentially comes down to what you're looking to get out of it

That said it's hard to beat asp.net mvc as it's 
* actively maintained
* consistent/easy to use naming conventions ( if that doesn't make sense, feel free to skip this :)
* well documented with source code/tutorials/handon labs et al 
* scales well out the box with other options available

I had not heard/seen the last 2 choices and while i did browse those links, i'm not going to invest my time learning/reading about them considering asp.net mvc is out there - my 0.02

Answer (score 0):

One that hasn't been mentioned here is [my favorite since 2014, NancyFx](http://nancyfx.org/), inspired by [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) from the Ruby world.

Almost no overhead, unlike the heavyweight official ASP.NET MVC.

It works with OWIN and Razor templates (& others too) and is easy to extend.

Best feature is you can write routes to both services and views in the same MVC controller class, which Nancy calls a "Module"

Comment: Nancy isn't exactly MVC based. This is evident from your last line.